# Creating 3d measurements with css or js

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, 3d

I would like to know if it is possible to create a 3d measurement somehow with css or js. So that there would be a width a height and a length. I know there is no conventional way to do this but I'm sure someone has come up with something more simple than the solutions I've been finder.

I want to know if it is possible to stack divs with different z-indexes or if there is an even better way to do this.

Here is a demo of the non-3d version of what i want [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eypj6jco/)

```
.one {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px inset #81ff14;
  text-align: center;
  animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
}

.two {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px outset #81ff14;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}

.survive {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 35px;
  max-width: 150px;
  margin: -175px auto;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.preserve {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

.containAnimation {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

And [this](http://www.pimped-pixels.net/forum/uploads/profile/photo-3.gif?_r=1444683080) is an example of what I want the end result to be like.

Comment: Have a look at the Codepen 3d animation demos, you bound to find something there -- http://codepen.io/tag/3d%20animation/  -- like this -- http://codepen.io/devilskitchen/pen/CBgsm

Comment: If you want this as a CSS only option, I'm not sure that a solution exists currently, Your 2D version is nice, but the rings never actually go in front of the words. there may be a way to add depth that translates during animation, I personally do not know of one, but I do know this is possible with Javascript and canvas, which generates an image, and is NOT CSS driven. If that's an acceptable answer, I'd suggest editing your question.

Comment: I said js is fine, I don't really know much about canvas though.